# Simple questions about random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

**1. Poisson random variable takes infinite number of values ?**

**2.  A binomial random variable takes infinite number of values ?**

I guess both sentences are true.
Namely, I think both of random variable can takes infinite number of values because a discrete random variable can only take on a finite or countably infinite number of values.

Am I right?

Oh, and,,

**3. Variance of a random variable is a variable.**

I guess Variance is a mass number for noting distribution of expected number so 3 is incorrect sentence.

I'm not certainly sure about these questions...

Comment: I guess you understand question 3 (but the question is still vague). For question 1 and 2, you need to know that both Poisson and Binomial are discrete random variable, but the support of Poisson is countably infinite and the support of Binomial is finite.

Comment: @BGM I have learned that ,in binomial, if possibility is too small and number of sample space are too large, these probability could be calculated to the approximation value of Poisson random variable. Can this knowledge be applied understanding your reply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I guess both sentences are true. Namely, I think both of random variable can takes infinite number of values because a discrete random variable can only take on a finite or countably infinite number of values.

Yes, they can be one or the other; but which is which ?

1. What is the support of a Poisson random variable, of mean $\lambda$ ?   Is this finite or countable infinite in cardinality?
2. What is the support of a Binomial random variable, of trial count $n$ and success rate $p$ ?   Is the cardinality of this finite or countable infinite?